# Why does the exit() function in C "never fail"?

Tags: c, exit

I was reading Head First C and it said "`exit()` is the only function that is guaranteed never to return a value and never to fail."

1. Are there other functions in C that are supposed to not return anything that might?
2. Why is it that `exit()` never ever fails?

Comment: How about reading the specification of `exit`? And read the standard to find other functions, if any. At a first glance, there is `abort`, which makes your prerequisite wrong. Looks like you should get a better learning resource.

Comment: In C11, there's also `_Exit()` and `quick_exit()` too; they never return. There's probably also a thread exit function that never returns either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there other functions in C that are supposed to not return anything that might?

Sort of. The `exec()` family (`execl`, `execlp`, `execve`, etc) will replace the current process with a new executable on success -- and, thus, will never return on success -- or return -1 (and set `errno`) if that fails.

> Why is it that `exit()` never ever fails?

How would it fail? There isn't anything that can keep a process from exiting.

Comment: The `exec` family very well can (and will) return under certain circumstances. From the process' view, they always return (if not, the process does not exist anymore). OP asked about a function that **never** returns.

Comment: @Olaf They return on failure -- either from the system call, or of the standard library code leading up to the system call. Upon success, the current process ceases to exist, so there's no return.

Comment: Read my edit. For the process calling them  they always return. If that is not instantly clear, think about it.

Comment: That becomes a bit of a philosophical question. :) They don't precisely _return_, though -- after `exec`, the new process starts fresh, with no knowledge of the call stack that led to `exec`.

Comment: Well, the calling process sees them return eventually. If they don't return, the calling process does not exist anymore. NEvertheless, that's not what OP asked for. The question is clearly OT anyway, we ae not a "list all functions" kinda site.